# Does Vim (NeoVim) remove mappings when sourcing vimrc?

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, load

I was editing my vimrc, and decided to remove a mapping based on some information I found on `<cr>`. So I deleted the mapping and called my `:SourceVimrc` command (`command SourceVimrc source $MYVIMRC`). To my surprise, when I pressed enter, it still performed the deleted mapping. I had to open a new session for the mapping to disappear.

I found the `:scriptnames` command, and that indicated to me that it was correctly loading the vimrc:

```
  1: ~/.config/nvim/init.vim                                                                    
  2: ~/.vimrc
```

So I added a new mapping for `<cr>` to make sure that sourcing works: `nnoremap <cr> <cr><cr>`, and that was loaded correctly.

I checked "Learn Vimscript the Hard Way", because I thought I remembered something there, but didn't find it if it is. On StackOverflow and here I didn't see this mentioned, although I'm surprised because I'm sure this is a question someone has asked before.

1. Is this correct? Does `:source $MYVIMRC` not remove mappings?
2. If this is true, can I change my command to remove all old mappings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`source` command executes ex-commands from the file being sourced. This implies nothing is removed unless you explicitly didn't add `unlet`, `unmap` and other commands to remove specific things.

Thus,

1. `:source $MYVIMRC` doesn't remove mappings
2. execute `:unmap <cr>`, do it for each mapping you want to "remove".

If you want to remove all mappings use `:h :mapclear`. Bear in mind that it would also remove mappings introduced by plugins and simple `:source $MYVIMRC` would not restore them.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't specific in my question (I updated it now), is it possible to remove **all** old mappings? For instance removing all custom mappings before loading the vimrc?